# Read a template javascript, then interporlate it and generete a javascript file Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, webpack, interpolation

I was researching about how could take a javascript template that I used for loading other javascript and css files, it's like a loader-file. I want take a javascript file an then interpolate the names of generated bundles files and finally create a new one file. I was thinking make it with webpack for doing that. But I haven't got something.

How could I do that? Is there any plugin for doing that?

This is a kind of template a file:

```js
(function myApp() {
    var styleUrls = [
      "https://cdn.mydomain.com/css/{nameoffile[0]}.css"
    ];
    var scriptUrls = [
        "https://cdn.mydomain.com/js/{nameoffile[1]}.js"
        "https://cdn.mydomain.com/js/{nameoffile[2]}.js"
        "https://cdn.mydomain.com/js/{nameoffile[3]}.js"
        "https://cdn.mydomain.com/js/{nameoffile[4]}.js"
    ];
  
    loadStyles(styleUrls);
    loadScripts(scriptUrls);

    function loadStyles(urls) {
      if (urls == null || urls.length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
  
      urls.forEach(function(href) {
        appendLinkTag(href);
      });
    }
  
    function loadScripts(urls) {
      if (urls == null || urls.length === 0) {
        return false;
      }
  
      urls.forEach(function(src) {
        appendScriptTag(src);
      });
    }
  
    function appendLinkTag(href) {
      var linkTag = document.createElement("link");
  
      linkTag.href = href;
      linkTag.rel = "stylesheet";
  
      if (document.head == null) {
        return false;
      }
  
      document.head.appendChild(linkTag);
    }
  
    function appendScriptTag(src) {
      var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
  
      scriptTag.src = src;
  
      if (document.body == null) {
        return false;
      }
  
      document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
    }
  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

DefinePlugin (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) ships with webpack, and is probably quite close to what you're looking for.